# use some twitter api to make people follow some account

Tags: php, api, iframe, twitter

I have a task to make people follow some account on twitter as soon as they fill a form on our website.
Can I do this using the twitter php api? Or just a redirect or iframe would do the job?

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: Are they already authenticated with Twitter when they've filled in the form? I'd be surprised if there weren't protections in Twitter against the redirect method but it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just need to read the api a bit,

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/friendships/create

Comment: apiwiki.twitter.com is old. You should use dev.twitter.com instead: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/friendships/create

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a Twitter user automatically follow another account until they give permission. You have to take them through OAuth authentication first, and then when they give you permission to modify their account you can add a follow. But automatically adding a follow without getting their explicit permission, meaning that you explain you are going to do this first, will get your account banned from Twitter. It is a serious violation of their terms of service.